# How to get a month with most dates listed

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have this URL, I get the HTML I can scrap anything on it no issue in that.

I can get all these dates in array, list anything.

My problem is, I want to know which is the most repeated month.

Example [here](http://offer.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&_trksid=p2047675.l2564&rt=nc&item=190889791426):

```
 User ID                                    Price    Quantity   Date of Purchase
 n***m ( 34Feedback score is 10 to 49)      GBP 1.95    1   Nov-11-13 12:33:49 PST   
 v***e ( 260Feedback score is 100 to 499)   GBP 1.95    1   Nov-07-13 04:52:25 PST   
 r***t ( 340Feedback score is 100 to 499)   GBP 1.95    1   Nov-05-13 19:14:07 PST   
 c***a ( 341Feedback score is 100 to 499)   GBP 1.95    1   Nov-03-13 01:33:42 PST   
 c***m ( 669Feedback score is 500 to 999)   GBP 1.95    1   Nov-02-13 12:08:03 PDT   
 1***a ( 158Feedback score is 100 to 499)   GBP 1.95    1   Nov-02-13 09:15:35 PDT   
 t***r ( 60Feedback score is 50 to 99)      GBP 1.95    1   Nov-01-13 15:13:37 PDT   
 o***o ( 84Feedback score is 50 to 99)      GBP 1.95    1   Oct-29-13 09:36:58 PDT   
 i***0 ( 10Feedback score is 10 to 49)      GBP 1.95    1   Oct-27-13 14:57:35 PDT   
 m***a ( 476Feedback score is 100 to 499)   GBP 1.95    1   Oct-23-13 08:58:14 PDT   
 u***e ( 20Feedback score is 10 to 49)      GBP 1.95    1   Oct-22-13 05:15:39 PDT   
 l***w ( 101Feedback score is 100 to 499)   GBP 1.95    1   Oct-17-13 10:55:17 PDT   
 6***6 ( 504Feedback score is 500 to 999)   GBP 1.95    1   Oct-15-13 15:31:10 PDT   
 m***c ( 329Feedback score is 100 to 499)   GBP 1.95    1   Oct-09-13 07:22:49 PDT   
 e***e ( 313Feedback score is 100 to 499)   GBP 1.95    1   Oct-03-13 22:39:48 PDT   
 0***z ( 11Feedback score is 10 to 49)      GBP 1.95    1   Oct-02-13 09:18:02 PDT   
 k***. ( 128Feedback score is 100 to 499)   GBP 1.95    1   Oct-01-13 10:02:15 PDT   
 v***v ( 127Feedback score is 100 to 499)   GBP 1.95    1   Sep-30-13 09:41:30 PDT   
 n***g ( 32Feedback score is 10 to 49)      GBP 1.95    1   Sep-30-13 09:19:57 PDT
```

You will see a item sold history there are many months in it. How can I get the month with the most dates? In here that would be `September`. I want to do this because this way I can get more accurate data regarding sale history as I have to calculate monthly average. Any ideas?

I am thinking of putting it all into a DataTable like :

```
Price   Quantity    Date    DateMonth
10             1         Nov-11-13  Nov
34             2         Nov-10-13  Nov
10             3         Oct-11-13  Oct
20             1         Oct-9-13   Oct
20             1         Oct-7-13   Oct
```

If is do so can we still not calculate the biggest month directly using a query?

Comment: Would it be suitable to just split all the dates into arrays with each array holding dates for a specific month and check which array is biggest?

Comment: @Chikilah actually i was looking for something like putting all this info in a DataTable and then use some query to sort it out is it possible GroupBy or something?

Comment: Supposedly you'd be able to GroupBy, but that would only give you a sorted list of dates if I'm catching what you're trying to do here. A table filled with dates would require something more than just that. I'd expect you could use a LINQ expression to complete the task though.

Comment: Ah! Well then it's quite simple with GroupBy.

var AmountofMonthDubs = list.GroupBy(DateMonth => DateMonth);

Editted, pressed enter a bit too quick.

Comment: @Chikilah Yes just as i thought but i want a query to do it all instead of me first calculation the biggest group then go through every row , What i want is it to do (price *quanity)/(monthRepeats)

So for oct (10*3)+(20*1)+(20*1) / totalQuantity in Oct(5) . Is this possible?

Comment: Hmm. I can't corrently see how you'd be able to do that to be honest. You'll have to know what to look for before you can calculate, else you'd be calculating the complete thing for every month and then in the end find the one you need, meaning you'd be running with much less performance than you would by just running over all month once first and then the one you need again.

Not sure if you're looking for ease of code or actual performance?

Comment: @Chikilah , you are rite, lets say i want to go toward better performance . So i should first get the Month . Then simply loop over the rows in the DataTable and calculate the values where monthcolum='OCT' rite? If so your expression above still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments - Here's the answer you're probably looking for:

```
var query = from d in DateMonth
            group d by d into g
            select new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()};

int MostAppearingMonthAmount = query.Max(g => g.Count);

IEnumerable<string> MostAppearingMonth = query
                                      .Where(g => g.Count == MostAppearingMonthAmount)
                                      .Select(g => g.Key);
```

You now have a list with the month (or months, if there's 2 or more months with the same amount) to iterate over. In order to just get one month, you can follow the statement with a simple ".FirstOrDefault()" and use a string instead of an IEnumerable.

Now all you need to do is calculate to your needs for the given month.

Comment: Im not so good with linq, Can you please explain what is DateMonth :| .And how to replicate it i am using a DataTable named averageTable with 4 columns .

  averageTable.Columns.Add("Price");
                                    averageTable.Columns.Add("Quantity");
                                    averageTable.Columns.Add("Date");
                                    averageTable.Columns.Add("Month");

Comment: DateMonth is the name of the object you're getting the values from (a List or Array in this case).

Comment: What you need to do is get a list of all the months - This is "DateMonth". Basically a list of Strings would do.

- Janes beat me to it ;)
I haven't worked a lot with DataTables, but I'd assume something along the lines of: averageTable.Columns.Get("Month").ToList(); into a List<string> ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the highest count of dates I firstly converted all the found dates to a `DateTime`:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(myString, @"[A-z]{1}[a-z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}");
```

This regex finds all the dates.

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
        foreach (Match item in matches)
        {
            dates.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(item.Value, "MMM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss", provider));
        }
```

I convert the dates to a DateTime object and group them month for month:

```
List<List<DateTime>> groupedMonths = dates.GroupBy(x => x.Month).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
```

Then I order the List by the count of the appearances of a month:

```
groupedMonths = groupedMonths.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToList();
```

After that I get the highest count of months by calling the first element of the List:

```
  string highestCountMonth = string.Format("The month {0} has most dates. Count: {1}", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(groupedMonths[0][0].Month), groupedMonths[0].Count);
```

[image: The List of DateTimes ordered by Months]

So in short it would be something like this:

```
List<List<DateTime>> groupedMonths = dates.GroupBy(x => x.Month).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToList();
```